# Blender 2.81's render device set to GPU doesn't show the viewpport render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

So I was tweaking my node setup in the world background when suddenly everything turned grey.

[image: Blender shading view with simple node setup for the world background with viewport render on and device set to GPU]

I tried to undo the steps but nothing changed. A bit later, I switched my rendering device to CPU and it worked like normal, but a bit slower.

[image: Blender shading view with simple node setup for Suzanne material with viewport render on and device set to CPU]

I checked my preferences and everything seemed fine to me.

[image: Blender User preferences window with Cycles Render Devices set to CUDA and GeForce GTX 1050 Ti box checked]

When I hit render with GPU device, it says "CUDA error at cuCtxCreate: Launch failed"

[image: Blender render window with said error]

I checked my other blender files and the problem persisted.

I would search a bit deeper on the web normally, but I have to finish a couple of VFX shots for next week so I want to everything to work as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems that restarting Blender resolves the problem.
However I know that this solution does not explain the cause, so if someone knows what it is or how to resolve it, go ahead

Comment: I get this after I hibernate my system.  It happens because a call to create a CUDA context failed, make sure you have the latest drivers and Cuda